# Why is Crystal Reports is adding the letter 'i' after the letter 'f'?

Tags: crystal-reports

While using Crystal Reports to generate PDFs with Visual Studio 2008 in a .NET 3.5 C# project I am experiencing a problem where the letter 'i' is being inserted after the letter 'f' in many (but not all) of my text boxes.

Here are two examples:

[image: 'fieel' instead of 'feel']
(`fieel` instead of `feel`)

[image: 'fiound' instead of 'found']
(`fiound` instead of `found`)

I asked one of my co-workers about this and they said they've experienced it before, and have solved it by deleting another text box in the document (not the one with the problem) and re-adding it, but the only way they found the correct text box to delete was to one at a time delete every text box and test the PDF generation (highly impractical as I have over 150 items).

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue. It seems to be related to the wrong version of USP10.DLL being used in the PDF creation - on my machine MS office seems to have one too. For now, I am just substituting the Calibri font. I dont have time to check the consequences of swapping out a DLL with a different version. Maybe modifying the path to give the folder with the working DLL higher priority will work. Ive not tested that yet.

[Link to SAP support](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/oss_notes_boj/sdn_oss_boj_bi/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes%7B6163636573733d36393736354636443646363436353344333933393338323636393736354637333631373036453646373436353733354636453735364436323635373233443330333033303331333533343337333933363331%7D.do)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the font for one of the fields and see if this will resolve the issue.